# Cant seem to find a channel name with Dsicord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

For some reason i cant seem to find a channel i listed in the code below with the name reports when i test the name my bot tells me thier is no channel called reports when thier is

```js
let Channel = findChannel(client, "reports")
```

Comment: `findChannel` isn't a native JS function.  How do you define it?

Comment: Where does the function `findChannel()` come from? It's not present in v11 or v12, and to my knowledge not in v13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, as stated within your comments, `findChannel` is not an actual function, therefore you will never get the expected result out of it. In order to find a channel by name, you must type the following line:

```
const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === "ChannelNamehere")
```

The `channel` const can be renamed to anything you'd like.

Best of luck with your coding.